# How to transfer all the ML Scripts, models etc. from databricks to AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-databricks

My databricks is hosted in AWS and i want to transfer all the notebooks, models etc from databricks to sagemaker. Can anyone tell me the procedure to be followed?